# Breakdown a string into two arrays using awk/sed/grep

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

Create two different arrays in shell/bash script from content in a text file which has details about different files. How do I extract directories into one array and filenames to another array, using awk/sed/grep?

I have a text file as show below

```
    2017-02-04      07:18   /temp/folder1/filename_20170204_something.txt  
    2017-03-04      07:18   /temp/folder2/filename_20170204_20170304.txt  
    2017-04-04      07:18   /temp/folder3/filename_20170404_.txt
```

```
directories_list= {folder1,folder2,folder3}  
file_list = {filename_20170204.txt,filename_20170304.txt,filename_20170404.txt}
```

Comment: Why isn't `temp` added to `directories_list`? Are there always exactly 28 characters before the first `/`?

Comment: So if the path is `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file` what is the rule for which directories should be stored? If the formatting is not consistent, what is the rule for determining where the path begins on the line?

Comment: Clarify exactly what you mean by `It is not consistent. temp is not needed`. Your input isn't consistent? Your output isn't consistent? `temp` shouldn't be present in the input? theres some algorithm for removing `temp` from the output? what? Are your paths always 2 dirs then a file or can they be varying depths?

Comment: @jhnc 
format remains same i.e

   /temp/folder1/filename,

Comment: /temp is consistent so I do not need that, Just Need dynamic folder list and filenames as two different arrays

Comment: Your output data doesn't look like valid array syntax for any of bash, awk, sed or grep. Which did you write your code in?

Comment: So are you saying the tool has to analyze all of the paths to figure it if any of the leading sequences of directories are common across all of the paths (e.g. if they all started with `/temp/foo/bar` then the tool needs to recognize that and not include temp or foo or bar in the output) or are you saying something else? Please just **think** about your requirements and then [edit] your question to clearly state them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `awk` to split the lines into columns, then `print` the column number for the folder and the column number for the file.  You can tell awk what the delimiting character is with the `-F` option.

This script stores the folders in one array and the files in another.

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDERS=() # declares FOLDERS as an array
FILES=() # declares FILES as an array
INPUT=input.txt # change to the path of your data file

while read LINE
do
  FOLDER=$(echo $LINE | awk -F / '{print $3}')
  FILE=$(echo $LINE | awk -F / '{print $4}')
  echo "Reading next line..."
  echo FOLDER: $FOLDER
  echo FILE: $FILE
  echo ""
  FOLDERS+=( "$FOLDER" ) # appends $FOLDERS to the FOLDERS array
  FILES+=( "$FILE" ) # appends $FILE to FILES array
done < $INPUT

# Now the FOLDERS array and FILES array have what you want

echo FOLDERS array: ${FOLDERS[@]}
echo FILES array: ${FILES[@]}
```

That's assuming you have the `input.txt` file in the same directory and it contains your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line, split with `read` and IFK, use basename and dirname, and read in the array:

```
cat <<EOF >file
    2017-02-04      07:18   /temp/folder1/filename_20170204_something.txt  
    2017-03-04      07:18   /temp/folder2/filename_20170204_20170304.txt  
    2017-04-04      07:18   /temp/folder3/filename_20170404_.txt    
EOF

dirs=() files=()
while IFS=' ' read -r _ _ path; do
    dirs+=("$(basename "$(dirname "$path")")")
    files+=("$(basename "$path")")
done <file
declare -p dirs files
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to handle the duplicate entries in the array & is there any specific order that you want to save the files.

If not you can use the below commands, (**removes duplicate entries & sorts based on filenames**)

```
folders=()
files=()

folders=`awk '{print $NF}' <INPUT_FILE> | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr | uniq`
files=`awk '{print $NF}' <INPUT_FILE> | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' | sort -nr | uniq`
```

Below is the explanation for the awk commands,

```
awk '{print $NF}' <INPUT_FILE> -> takes the last field in the input file
awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' -> cuts the last filed with / as delimiter and takes the penultimate column
```

Hope this helps !